# Настройка Qt под Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, qt

Всем доброе время суток!
Установил я на свой новенький ноут Ubuntu 16.04 LTS и решил поставить сюда Qt.
Скачал, значит я, установочный файл для Qt версии 5.7 c оф.сайта, установил в папку opt/qtsdk/. Все хорошо. Запускаю QtCreator, создаю стандартное(оконное) приложение, делаю сборку, все запускается и работает.

Потом, если делать все через терминал и утилиту qmake, то проект не собирается и qmake ругается на якобы отсутствие заголовочных файлов, но опять же, через QtCreator все работает.

Вот вывод ошибки, которые выдаёт qmake:
делаю так:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Пишет:

```
......
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
mainwindow.h:4:23: fatal error: QMainWindow: Нет такого файла или каталога
compilation terminated.
.....
```

В чем может быть проблема?

В переменную окружения PATH я прописывал путь к qmake:

```
sudo -s gedit /etc/profile
PATH=/opt/qtsdk/5.7/gcc_64/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Вот структура проекта:

```
main.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"QMainWindow: Нет такого файла или каталога" означает, что одноименный включаемый файл не может быть найден по путям поиска включаемых файлов. Решается указанием в pro-файле в INCLUDEPATH соответствующего каталога, например.

Кстати, зачем вы использовали установщик с оф.сайта, а не ставили из репозитория?

Comment: Это что-то типо `/opt/qtsdk/5.7/gcc_64/include/` ?
Ну в репозитории же обновляются медленно версии, не факт что там последняя Qt.

Comment: @rekrut возможно. Где именно у вас этот файл я не знаю.

Comment: Кстати, подскажите пожалуйста репозиторий, где можно скачать Qt. Попробую так поставить.

Comment: @rekrut да вроде все стандартные репы: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=qtbase5-dev

Comment: По мне так из репозитория удобнее. Может версия не самая новая, зато обновляется самостоятельно. Хотите самую последнюю Qt - клонируйте себе их git-репозиторий (ссылка есть на оф. сайте), соберите и пользуйтесь на здоровье. Заодно иногда полезно в исходниках посмотреть как та или иная вещь реализована.

Comment: Это все теперь понятно, а вот как теперь снести ту Qt, что я с оф сайта установил чтобы это было не больно?

Comment: @rekrut не представляю, попробуйте make uninstall или почитайте readme.